# PayPal Partner Referrals API URL

Tags: node.js, api, paypal

I am having trouble setting up Partner Referrals when calling the PayPal API using Node.

Every time I attempt to call the API I receive the following error:

> error: "invalid_token"
> error_description: "The token passed in was not found in the system"

According to the [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/partner-referrals/v2/) the URL to call is `https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/customer/partner-referrals`

Looking at the URL and the error message, I believe I am getting this error because I am using production credentials, not sandbox. However, I cannot find any documentation showing the production URL for this.

Am I correct in believing this is the sandbox URL? What is the production URL if so?

Ive followed the [onboarding checklist](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/multiparty/seller-onboarding/before-payment/) but cant seem to make this work.

Here is my code:

```
 getAuthToken = async () => {
    const clientIdAndSecret = "mylongsecret";
    const authUrl = "https://api-m.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token";
    const base64 = Buffer.from(clientIdAndSecret).toString('base64')

    const response = await fetch(authUrl, { 
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Accept-Language': 'en_US',
            'Authorization': `Basic ${base64}`,
        },
        body: 'grant_type=client_credentials'
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
}

setUpMerchant = async () => {
    let authData = await this.getAuthToken();
    const partnerUrl = "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/customer/partner-referrals";
    let data = {
        "operations": [
          {
            "operation": "API_INTEGRATION",
            "api_integration_preference": {
              "rest_api_integration": {
                "integration_method": "PAYPAL",
                "integration_type": "THIRD_PARTY",
                "third_party_details": {
                  "features": [
                    "PAYMENT",
                    "REFUND"
                 ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "products": [
          "EXPRESS_CHECKOUT"
        ],
        "legal_consents": [
          {
            "type": "SHARE_DATA_CONSENT",
            "granted": true
          }
        ]
    };
    const request = await fetch(partnerUrl, { 
        method: 'POST', 
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer '+authData.access_token, 
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'data': data,
        }, 
    });
    const partnerData = await request.json();
    return partnerData;
}
```

**Edit: I discovered the issue was I was running a `GET` request instead of a `POST`. The accepted answer is the correct URL**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> According to the documentation the URL to call is https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/customer/partner-referrals

The production URL does not have `sandbox.` in the domain.